# creating dummies out of multiple columns in a dataframe in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dummy-variable

i have a dataframe where i have identified 5 columns which need to be converted to dummies, but i am not able to create dummies from multiple columns.
The entire dataframe is numerical in nature, no categorical values.
consider i have 100 variables which i have, and out of those 100 columns, 5 should be converted to dummies. namely V1,V4,V5,V15,V52..
how can i do it, i can't find any syntax for that, that worked for me, how to create dummies out of multiple columns in a single dataframe and concat all the dummies in the original dataframe.

i've tried this code, but so far it didn't work

```
new_dum = ['V1','V4','V5','V15','V52']
dumy_col = pd.get_dummies(traindf[new_dum], drop_first = True)
dumy_col
```

This is the output that i got

[image: This is the output that i got]

Comment: "it didn't work" - _how_ did it not work? What did you expect it to do? What happened instead?

Comment: "The entire dataframe is numerical in nature, no categorical values.". Why do you need dummy variables in that case?

Comment: @Supratim Haldar The data is arrange numberwise , for example if we have ranges from 20-40,40-50,50-60 they are changed to 1,2,3 and so on thats why i need to create dummies of the data cause those vatiables numerically won't benifit my data but as a subcategory it will benifit my analysis

Comment: @ForceBru it gave me the columns as it is, i will post the answer i got

Comment: i've posted the output that i got

Comment: can someone tell me how to concat seperate dummy columns and add them to the main dataframe(traindf) in my case

Answer (score 0):

This syntax worked

```
dumy_col = pd.get_dummies(traindf, columns=['V1','V4','V5','V6','V44'], 
drop_first = True)
dumy_col
```